# express-validator showing undefined for defined values

Tags: forms, express, validation

I'm sending data to server using fetch:

```
const post = async(data)=>{
console.log(data)
const response = await fetch("/comments", {  
method: "POST",
body:JSON.stringify(data)
});
return response.json();
};
```

**data** is console logged, it's a standard object with keys and values. And it arrives to server, same keys and values.

On the server I run this express-validation for sanitizing:

```
router.use(express.json());
router.post("/",
      body("email").isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
      body("name").trim().escape(),
      body("msg").not().isEmpty().trim().escape(),
      (req,res,next)=>{
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      console.log(errors);
      if (!errors.isEmpty())  { res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() }); return};
      try{
      saveComment(req.body, (err,doc) => {
          err?  next(createError(500, "Couldn't save the document. Try again.")):
          res.json({msg:"saved"});
          });
      } catch(e) {
      next(createError(500, ISE));
      }
      });
```

And what I get is:

```
Result {
  formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: undefined,
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'email',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      value: undefined,
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'msg',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}
POST /comments 422 17.821 ms - 126
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **header** in the fetch function:

```
headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
```